# Cancel on confirm dialog still submits link

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, haml

I'm attempting to have a link confirm before submitting and properly cancel. Below is my line of code:

```
= button_to 'Complete Disconnect', {:controller => 'disconnects', :action => 'physical_disconnect', :id => d.id }, :data => { :role => 'button', :confirm => 'Are You Sure?' }
```

I get the dialog but it submits when i click cancel. I'm using jquery mobile on this page. Any good way i can do this?

EDIT

So i've also tried:

```
= link_to 'Complete Disconnect', {:controller => 'disconnects', :action => 'physical_disconnect', :id => d.id }, :class => "disconnect", :onclick => "return confirm('are you sure?')", :data => { :role => "button" }
```

and using this javscript:

```
:javascript
  $('.disconnect').click(function(){
    var url = this.href
    if(confirm("You Sure?")){
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        success: function(){
          console.log("Success")
        },
      });
    }
  });
```

Cancel still submits the request

Comment: Add `data-rel=back` to cancel button.

Comment: Nope, the confirmation dialog doesn't pop up at all.

Comment: Are you using JQM 1.4? How do you call the dialog?

Comment: looks like i'm using 1.1.1 :data => { :role => 'button', :confirm => 'Are You Sure?' } is the code that sets up the confirm, which from what i've read should just work right?